# Which is a better? GPRS SIM800L or GPRS SIM900?

Tags: arduino-uno, json

I will implementate the GPRS technologity in my Arduino project, but before buy the module, I want to know which is a better. If GPRS SIM800L or GPRS SIM900? My needs are send JSON array through POST request.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Better from what perspective?

Comment: From perspective of a vehicle running. Which has more confiability/stability in sending data? Or why is better one than other? Thanks.

Comment: If it's for a car, maybe you have in mind "location of the car". In that case notice SIM800 dont have GPS. The location a SIM800 can give is the location of tower cell which can be far from the device. For sending data, saving them and so on I suggest to have a look at hologram.io SIM card. I use them for IoT project and that's pretty nice.

Comment: Hi Peter, I understand your comment about the GPS. Actualy in my project use a GPS module of UBLOX, the NEO-6M. Also thanks you for share me your hologram technology, it looks very interesting and useful. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

SIM900 is older type. SIM800L has FM build it and it uses same AT cmds as SIM900.
Also, they are in same quadband. I guess both will work just fine.